# what are possible performance issues on using python over java for Android App development?

Tags: java, android, python, performance

I am new to Android and was seeking for an app (email client) which has a nice filter system, but after a lot of Googling and Android market browsing, its seems none of the email client available for Android provide such features. (at least the free ones don't). So, finally I decided to develop one myself. Now the problem is I wish to develop this in Python, but I am concerned about the efficiency issue. Thus, the questions are:

1. Apart from limited API exposure for Python on Android what all factors do I need to watch out for when choosing between Java and Python?
2. Moreover, I guess we need to install a Python compiler on the users machince with our Python app, so does that mean more memory usage and reduced performance?

P.S. Considering performance and memory usage JAva seems better? To what excent using python can affect performance and memory usage?

Comment: Im not sure if there's GUI support for Python on Android

Comment: @FabioDiniz There is, but I don't know how extensive (e.g. I know it can do toast, buttons, pop up text entry boxes...).

Comment: I see this as a totally legit question, write code in Java or Python for Android....

Comment: @JPM It is subjective.  There is no "right" answer.  Subjective questions are not allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and run Python on Android, its just a linux box but if you doing anything graphical either use the android GUI/Java or openGL.  Check out this [link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10940) to install Python on Android.  Python you can use for fast scripting and running some programs quickly.  But for Android you might be hindered a little...

Comment: I understand SL4, but using a Python based App forces client to install a Python Compiler in their Android machine, thus would this cause more memory usage and reduced performance than the same App written in JAVA?

Comment: Yes you are correct, so I don't recommend it.  I would stick with Java then as the user doesn't have to do anything else other than install your app.